# WPF quickstart documentation

Tags: wpf, documentation

I am totally new to WPF and looking for good quickstart documentation to start with. I will buy the book WPF Unleashed from Adam Nathan, but thats more a reference than a quickstart i think.
I just want you to tell me your favorite links and books and maybe demo applications concerning wpf development.

Focus of answers should be on best practices, good readable introductions (i hate the link farms on msdn ;) and comprehensive references.

EDIT: I will try to assemble all suggestions in a short list sorted by type.
And please try to give a short reason *why* you suggest especial that link or that book.

**Books:**

- [WPF Unleashed by Adam Nathan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917)
- Pro WPF: Windows Presentation Foundation in .NET 3.0
- [Programming WPF by Chris Sells and Ian Griffiths](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596510373)

**Blogs:**

- [Blog about data binding in WPF by Beatriz Costa](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/)
- [Ask Dr. WPF](http://www.drwpf.com/blog/)
- [Guided tour on WPF](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/a-guided-tour-of-wpf/)

**Links:**

- [MSDN Hands-on Lab](http://www.microsoft.com/switzerland/msdn/de/presentationfinder/detail.mspx?id=104056) from Microsoft about WPF
- [msdn on getting started with WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742119.aspx)
- [windowsclient.net](http://windowsclient.net/)
- [Lernwpf.com](http://learnwpf.com/)
- [Series of articles on Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BeginWPF1.aspx)
- [Some WPF videos on windowsclient.net](http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx)

**Demo Applications:**

- [Family.Show](http://www.vertigo.com/familyshow.aspx) from Vertigo
- [Babysmash](http://www.hanselman.com/babysmash/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent [Hands on Lab for building an Outlook-esque UI using Blend and Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/switzerland/msdn/de/presentationfinder/detail.mspx?id=104056). It is a bit out of date in terms of Blend 2.5, but it is instrumental in learning how to use WPF and effectively using Blend.

Comment: Great - thats exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Check out the Channel9 [Videos](http://channel9.msdn.com/Media/Videos/) and [Screencasts](http://channel9.msdn.com/Media/Screencasts/) about WPF.

Another resource to get started is the official Microsoft WPF site at [windowsclient.net](http://windowsclient.net).

Answer (score 2):

My Favourite Book is
Pro WPF: Windows Presentation Foundation in .NET 3.0 (
http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590597826)

Comment: Can you tell me your key reasons, why you prefer that book over other?

Answer (score 0):

I have read most of the WPF books on the market. Programming WPF by Chris Sells and Ian Griffiths is the best and Pro WPF the second best IMHO. Just my two cents.